# Chrome Extension blocking webRequest doesnt seem to be working at all

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am just trying to get the [MDN example chrome extension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/http-response) working. here is the manifest.json

```
{
  "description": "Altering HTTP responses",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "http-response-filter",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url":
    "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/http-response",
  "icons": {
    "48": "SA-48x48.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

and here is the background.js

```
function listener(details) {
  console.log("******listen");
  let filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
  let decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
  let encoder = new TextEncoder();

  filter.ondata = event => {
    let str = decoder.decode(event.data, { stream: true });
    // Just change any instance of Example in the HTTP response
    // to WebExtension Example.
    str = str.replace(/Example/g, "WebExtension Example");
    filter.write(encoder.encode(str));
    filter.disconnect();
  };

  return {};
}
console.log("******");
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  { urls: ["https://example.com/*"], types: ["main_frame"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

So i expect it to

- put a couple console.logs out when i load `example.com`
- modify "Example" to "WebExtension Example" as stated by the MDN folks

however, it doesn't work at all for me (I am using Chrome and i added it to my Extensions as an unpacked Extension, i've done other chrome extensions before but this is my first time doing a background script).

Is it possible that something is blocking this background script from running? have i just not configured it in the right way? Please point me in the right direction, thanks very much.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support modifying the response body so it won't work.

Comment: i don't think that's true, i got this directly from MDN and i've seen other extensions (eg SmileAlways) that use this API. i think there is a setup here I'm not getting right?

Comment: I deleted my post since it wasn't actually an answer to your question - comments are better suited for suggestions.  
The console.log should print something to the console if the script is loaded - so there may be something preventing it from loading. By the way - are you inspecting the background page of your extension when debugging?

Comment: @swyx, you didn't check the code of SmileAlways apparently. It doesn't use browser.webRequest.filterResponseData. It's [not implemented](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=filterResponseData) in Chrome as you can also see in the [documentation for Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Also, `browser` namespace is Firefox-specific, it's not present in Chrome either so you need a polyfill.

Comment: hey guys - so I started work on this again 50 minutes ago and now I have resolved everything. So, yes, you are right, its `chrome` instead of `browser`. also I didnt know that it prints to the console of the BACKGROUND page instead of the main console page. Figured it out in the end, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Chrome Extension needs to "ask" for permissions to use the webRequest API so that users of the extension will get notified what the extension may be able to do.

Try adding this to your `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
]
```

Comment: dont know why you got downvoted.. markedyou as correct as your background page inspection hint was the correct thing to do and that was exactly what i needed to debug everything else. thank you very much.